# pm2 not starting properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I am trying to start a nodejs application in pm2 in bluehost shared hosting.

I am running following command to start the server:

```
pm2 start ./bin/www
```

then it shows following message and server is not starting.

```
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/home4/[username]/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[PM2] Starting /home4/[username]/manufacturing/files/bin/www in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
```

I tried starting the server using `node ./bin/www` command and it start successfully but when I am using `pm2` it is not working.

further when i run `pm2 list`, it shows nothing

```
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/home4/[username]/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
┌────┬────────────────────┬──────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id │ name               │ mode     │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ memory   │
└────┴────────────────────┴──────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

**UPDATE**

```
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/home4/pineoran/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[TAILING] Tailing last 15 lines for [all] processes (change the value with --lines option)
Aborted
```

what should i do??

Comment: You can try this also `sudo pm2 restart ./bin/www`

Comment: Unfortunately don't have sudo access as I am using in shared hosting

Answer (score 1):

Your NodeJS application should have a main js file to run.
Go to project path and then:

```
pm2 start server.js
```

This is what I used. Then in `pm2 list`, there was my server process running.

Comment: my main file is not a js file it's `./bin/www` a file without extension as it was generated using express-generator :(

Comment: @HelloWorld does your service work though it's not showed in the list? I mean .. from outside

Answer (score 1):

You must have `superuser` privilege when you use port below 1024. In local computer, we mostly have `superuser` privilege, so you could start your node server with 80 port. But in the server, it depend on your user privilege. If you have `superuser` privilege in the server, you also can start your node with 80 port. But, if you didn't have it, you only can use port above 1024.

You could simply use `node ./bin/www` to start server to check what kind of error message show up. If error message say you couldn't listen the port, then you should change your `port` to other, such as 3000, 4000. And then use `node ./bin/www` to start server again. If you successfully start your server with `node ./bin/www`, you also could use `pm2` to start server.

Last, when you use `pm2` to start node application, you should use complete file name. If your node file is `www.js`, you shoud use `pm2 start www.js` instead of `pm2 start www`. But, if your node file is `www`, you should use `pm2 start www`.

More detail about [List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).
There is a section (Well-known ports) talk about priviliged port.

Comment: I don't have `superuser` privilege in my shared hosting. But i can start the application by using `node bin/www` successfully :(

Comment: @HelloWorld You could use `pm2 logs` after you use `pm2 start ./bin/www` to check the problem. What is the result of `pm2 logs`?

Comment: Which port did you use?

Comment: it shows nothing in the logs. I have edited the question. I am using  port 7070

Comment: @HelloWorld If it works in your local computer, what is the version of pm2 and node in your server and your local computer? Does it work with curl 7070 port when you use node ./bin/www in server?

Comment: I recommend you use a very simple express sample (Only one get router, no other db connection or something) to test in your server. I think there is other problem to make your node.js failed. And which server library do you use? express or koa?

Comment: yes I have tested with a simple application. It works as `npm start` but when i use `pm2 start app.js` it doesn't work on the server

Comment: Okay, I almost can't come up with new thought. Is it same version of pm2 and node between local and server? Or could you open a new server to do test?